# Stored procedure with parameters to return specific multiple columns, not all (*)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Currently, I have a stored procedure that returns all the columns `(Select *)`. I am using this stored procedure to retrieve data from multiple tables, each table with different number of columns and obviously different column names, so `Select *` is convenient. However, now I need to retrieve only specific columns from each table so I want to pass the parameters something like this:

```
SELECT @param1, @param2, @param3, etc. 
FROM @tableName 
WHERE columnName = @tableId
```

The problem here is the number of parameters to be passed for the columns isn't set, as the table can have any number of columns. Is there a way to use some kind of loop or dynamic assignment so that I can pass any number of parameters as column names?

I know that I can filter out only the columns I want to use, and just leave out the rest, but that doesn't work in my case. I need the stored procedure to NOT return some specific columns with sensitive data.

I am using SQL Server 2008, ASP.NET MVC 4, and C# in my application.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good fit for a stored procedure. Depending on what sort of logic the procedure uses, is it an option to define a view or a table-valued function instead and write dynamic queries on that? You're doing the determination of what columns are allowed on the client side anyway.

Comment: This is an interesting problem. Dynamic SQL anyone? He would have to pass the columns he wants as a varchar. Build a query within a query and exec it.

Comment: Don't use a stored procedure.  The SQL statement is a string so you can compose a custom string in c#.  The parameters is CSV ( param1, param2, param3) which can be formed using String.Join(",", array).

Comment: This whole thing you are describing sounds to me like you are trying to create "one proc to rule them all". A generic proc that can receive the columns and the table to select. This is a very bad idea and is akin to making a single method in your dotnet code that can do everything based on the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to modify your stored procedure, you can easily put the required columns definitions as a parameter and use an auto-created temporary table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetDiffDataExample
      @columnsStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) -- required columns statement (e.g. "field1, field2")
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @query = N'SELECT ' + @columnsStatement + N' INTO ##TempTable FROM dbo.TestTable'
    EXEC sp_executeSql @query
    SELECT * FROM ##TempTable
    DROP TABLE ##TempTable
END
```

In this case you don't need to create a temp table manually - it is created automatically.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hmm, wouldn't be easier to just forget about the stored procedure and create a function on the C# part to construct and execute the query? at the end they will do the same, construct dynamically a query and execute it

Comment: This has the problem now of concurrency though because you are using a global temp table. And you really should avoid using the sp_ prefix even in examples.

Comment: What does the `'N'` represent in the `query`? Could you also show a sample of what the `columnsStatement` would look like? 

@Gusman I need to use a stored procedure instead of directly accessing the table from database, for security purpose.

Comment: Inappropriate use of the spoiler tag IMO

Comment: This also has no protection against SQL injection. If you're going this route, at least pass a TVP with the column names, or (re-)parse the input. Don't just concatenate strings.

Comment: @Gusman : Yeah may be an easier way, but his query was to create a stored procedure (Refer title)

Comment: Ok @SeanLange. Editing of the Answer is welcome.
 Why is that we should'nt use sp_ prefixes? May I know please?

Comment: @Ruban.J Yeah, that's right, just guessed if that was truly a requirement, and it seems it is as the user stated on the comments. :/

Comment: @Ruban.J check out this article. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you . I will be avoiding it in the near future.

Comment: @BivoKasaju the N indicates that the string is nvarchar instead of varchar. If you omit the N in this case it will work fine because there will be an implicit conversion of the string literal to nvarchar

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass one parameter that is a comma-delimited string of the columns you want to select and build a dynamic sql string.

```
@sql = 'SELECT ' + @param + ' FROM MyTable...';
EXECUTE (@sql);
```

If you use a dynamic sql solution, you should take care to guard against sql injection attacks.

You might also consider continuing to get all columns from the stored procedure, and showing only the columns the user wants in the front end.

Comment: I am using the stored procedure to export the table to excel, and it exports all the columns that are being returned. Yes, I can show only the columns I want for displaying purpose, but I can't in case of exporting. So I HAVE to make sure only the required columns are being returned.

Comment: Ok, then disregard my suggestion about using the front end, and only use the first half of my answer.

Comment: Is there still a possibility of sql injection when I am hard coding the parameters to be passed to the stored procedure in my application, and there is no user input in the website? All the users can do is select from a list of options, but they have no way of inputting text to pass as parameters.

Comment: No, if the users can't free-write their own inputs, and your website is secure, then I wouldn't worry about sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

Although I really do not like the stored procedure approach for this problem (I agree with @Gusman that building the query in C# is a better approach) you can make a stored procedure work without opening yourself to SQL Injection attacks. The following example is one simple way to do this:

Let's say that the table in question has the columns named `COL1`, `COL2`, and `COL3`. The stored procedure would accept a `varchar(max)` parameter named `@IncludeCols` and have code like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @IncludeCols LIKE '%#COL1#%' THEN COL1 ELSE '' END AS COL1, 
       CASE WHEN @IncludeCols LIKE '%#COL2#%' THEN COL2 ELSE '' END AS COL2,
       CASE WHEN @IncludeCols LIKE '%#COL3#%' THEN COL3 ELSE '' END AS COL3
FROM <Table name>
WHERE <Where clause>
```

Yes, a column of every name will be returned, but data will only come from columns whose names are in the parameter. For example, if you wanted `COL1` and `COL3`, the parameter value would be `#COL1#COL3#`. The `#` is important and must be on each side of every column name or any `LIKE` clause could get a false positive match.

Answer (score 0):

If this is to export data to Excel then the best approach is likely to have a stored procedure that returns all of your columns minus the ones that should **never** be exported (passwords, other protected data, timestamps perhaps) and then filter out any additional unwanted columns in your front end.

You should **never** be using `SELECT *` for several reasons. Define what your application needs and program to that.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to do, select all columns minus the ones with sensitive data. But the SQL way to do is select all the required columns (not select all minus one), so I'm trying to figure out how to pass column names as parameters when I don't have a fixed number; they vary according to tables. I did get a few solutions here, so I will try them all and see which one works the best.

Comment: If you don't know what columns you might want from your stored procedure when you write it then you've likely got a design issue. You don't write your stored procedure with `SELECT *` or with variable columns. You list them out.

Comment: That is because I am using this stoproc for multiple tables, not just one. All tables have variable column numbers, hence I need to pass parameters with column names respective to the table I am calling.

Comment: Right, and there's your problem - you're trying to write one stored procedure to do many things.